# VIM executing current line as VIM command

Tags: vim, command

Is it possible to execute a **VIM** command inside a text file that is opened by **VIM**? For example we can have the following text and we would like to execute `:help w` without typing it.

```
  Read the text in the help window to find out how the help works.
  Type  CTRL-W CTRL-W   to jump from one window to another.
  Type    :q <ENTER>    to close the help window.

  You can find help on just about any subject, by giving an argument to the
  ":help" command.  Try these (don't forget pressing <ENTER>):

    :help w
    :help c_CTRL-D
    :help insert-index
    :help user-manual
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create the following map to execute the command defined in the current line:

```
nnoremap <c-e> :exe getline('.')<cr>
```

Placing the cursor in the line with `:help w` and typing `Ctrl+E` will open the help page.

Comment: Thanks it is working; I have a quick question though. How is it different than `:exec '!'.getline('.')`?

Is **.** string concatenation operator in **VIM** commands, what does it stand for in these cases?

Comment: Yes, the dot `.` is used for string concatenation (see `:help expr-.`) in Vim's command-line. Puting a `!` after the command (`exec!`) will return `No ! allowed` because only certain commands accept `!`. See `:help _!` .

Comment: @Vesnog That would execute the current line as a shell command. See `:help :!`.